# Draw straight line and create curve line dragging line

Tags: ios, drawing, uibezierpath, bezier

I would like to create an instrument for my app that draws straight line first and on the second touch and move user can create an adjustable curve line.
So the idea is to set middle point of curve line when user touches and moves second time.

And i have no idea how to check second touch and work with previous path.

This method i use to draw simple line

Thank you!

```
- (void)setInitialPoint:(CGPoint)firstPoint
{
self.firstPoint  = firstPoint;
//[self moveToPoint:firstPoint]; //add yourStartPoint here
///[self addLineToPoint:endPoint];
}

- (void)moveFromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint
{
self.lastPoint = endPoint;

   //  [self addLineToPoint:self.lastPoint];// add yourEndPoint here
```

}

```
- (void)draw { 
   UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
//draw a line

[path  moveToPoint:self.firstPoint]; //add yourStartPoint here
[path addLineToPoint:self.lastPoint];// add yourEndPoint here

[self.lineColor setStroke];

[path setLineWidth:3.0];

 [path stroke];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Second touch - hold a variable to track your state.

Curve - don't try to change a path, just use the start and end of the first line and create a `UIBezierPath` to draw as the user moves the touch point. Move the bezier to the start point, then use `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:` using the end point and the current touch location.

To make it really fun, allow the user to touch with 2 fingers while drawing the second line and then you have values for both of the control points.

Comment: Thank you, @Wain . Just need to find out how to track touches.. Becasue i have other instruments (like dashed line, arrow) and for them i need just one touch.

Comment: UIGestureRecofnizer or UIView (touchesBegan:).

Answer (score 0):

if you just have to fiddle with the middle point of the line,learning quadratic curve to would be simple for you as it would be having only one control point instead of two.first carefully observe the nature of the cureve and depending on your choice(quadratic or bezier) adjust the control point1,cp2(if there),the start and the end point
the following link will help you understand the nature of bezier curve in a very simple way
[link](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/canvas-curves/bezier-curve.html)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I just cant store path and after line was drawn change it to curve with two fingers! I'm new in developing and i just need small piece of code, please! Usually understand from just small piece of code)))) sorry!